# How to add blinking cursor to editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My EditText code is:

```
  <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/et_report_text" android:textColor="#414141"
            android:layout_weight="1.6" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:textSize="12dp" android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

            />
```

But there are no cursor on it, i try to add`android:cursorVisible="true"`but it did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

Answer (score 0):

try this 
android:textColor="#000000"

android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

or try this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/lTTObybu9_c